# GuessingGame Xcode Thread Breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode

```
//
//  GGViewController.m
//  GuessingGame
//
//  Created by NEIU Developer on 9/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NEIU Developer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GGViewController.h"


@interface GGViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputText;
-(IBAction)guess:(id)sender;

@end
@implementation GGViewController
-(IBAction)guessNumber:(id)sender
{

    if([field.text intValue] == randomNum)
    {
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Correct!"];

    }
    else if([field.text intValue] > randomNum)
    {
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Incorrect, Guess Lower!"];
    }
    else if([field.text intValue] < randomNum)
    {
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Incorrect, Guess Higher!"];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    randomNum = arc4random() % 11;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Between 1-10"];
    self.inputText.delegate=self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


- (IBAction)guess:(id)sender {

}
@end


// nssstring to integer

//getting random number to objective c

//int r =arc4random() 

____________________________

//
//  GGViewController.h
//  GuessingGame
//
//  Created by NEIU Developer on 9/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NEIU Developer. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GGViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{

    int randomNum;
    IBOutlet UITextField *field;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

-(IBAction)guessNumber:(id)sender;

@end

_____________________
```

I created a basic xcode guessing game. The game allows you to guess a number between 1-10, and tells you if it is lower high or correct. When I run the game, it goes back to the xcode application and the simulator goes into the background. After that it highlights this line in green:
  if([field.text intValue] == randomNum)

It says thread 1 breakpoint 1.1

What is this error?

Comment: What does it output when you log `field.text` and `randomNum`?

Comment: It is suppose to output one of those responses, but instead it goes back to the xcode application and exits out of the simulator. Nothing happens!

Comment: You're not logging anything. Put this line before your if statements of your `guessNumber` function and post the output: `NSLog(@"%@ == %i", field.text, randomNum);`

Comment: Is it possible that you just have a breakpoint set and the debugger is stopped at that line of code?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@ == %i", field.text, randomNum);
    if([field.text intValue] == randomNum)
like this? 

A little confused, my bad!

Comment: Sure, that'll work lol. Just put the line I typed somewhere before that if statement and run it.

Comment: ahh nope:/ the same error occurred!

Comment: What makes you think it's an error?  Sounds like it's just a breakpoint.  Try disabling all breakpoints and running again.

Comment: @RishiG - I've only used xCode a few times. I usually use java, how would I do that?

Comment: I deleted a breakpoint and now it doesn't work at all and goes black.. uh oh

Comment: Wait, that actually made the app to work consecutively! But no output is printing out in the label.

Comment: wait... i think i figured it out. I just forgot to put the label from the storyboard into the code... haha. Thanks guys! RishiG, deleting the breakpoints fixed it and so did that nslog line rebello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is running this method, guess.
    -(IBAction)**guess**:(id)sender {
    //empty method
    }

But you've put all of your code for that method in a different method, guessNumber.
    -(IBAction)**guessNumber**:(id)sender {
    //your code is here
    }

So when you click the button, it's running the empty method guess, and your guessNumber method is not being called.

Comment: It gave me an error when i made them both guessNumber and when i added the button into the controller.m it doesn't respond when i press guess.

Comment: You've already added your button and called its method "guess." So if you cut the code from your guessNumber method and paste it into the guess method, it should work. You don't need any method for guessNumber because you're never calling it, you're only calling guess.

Comment: That ends up creating an error. There is a guess at the bottom as well. Not really sure why.

Comment: That came from when you added the button from the storyboard. You only need one method for the guessing. So if you put all the code in that guess method at the bottom and remove all other methods you've created related to guessing, it should work. In your .h you can change the guessNumber method to guess, since you don't have a guessNumber method.

Comment: all of that gave me this error:
//
//  main.m
//  GuessingGame
//
//  Created by NEIU Developer on 9/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NEIU Developer. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "GGAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([GGAppDelegate class]));
    }
}